# Dynamic highcharts pie chart with drilldown

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am creating my charts based on arrays stored in a div data attribute. The pie is displayed but I can't seem to be able to create the drilldown. My data array is created by js and it looks something like this:

```
[
Object {name="Drive", y=1, color="#1068C7", drilldown="drive"}, 
Object { name="Ride", y=2, color="#11A852",  drilldown="ride"},
Object { name="Swim", y=1, color="#23ED1C", drilldown="swim"}
]
```

My proposed drilldown array outputs this on console.log()

```
[
Object { name="Tiger Team", data=1, id="swim"}, 
Object { name="Tiger Team", data=1, id="drive"}, 
Object { name="Spider Team", data=1, id="ride"}, 
Object { name="Bird Team", data=1, id="ride"}
]
```

What I need to do is click on "Ride" and get a drill down of all users in this categrory, that would be `Object { name="Spider Team", data=1, id="ride"},`  and `Object { name="Bird Team", data=1, id="ride"}`

My chart initialization script looks something like this:
  draw_chart(chart_div);

```
  var chart = $("#"+chart_div).highcharts();
      chart.addSeries({
            type: 'pie',
            name: "Num of results",
            data: pie_json
      });
```

How can I associate the two arrays and have one drill down to the other?

Comment: Are you sing [`drilldown.js`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown) in your case? It should work by default, so maybe you forget to include `drilldown.js` file? If you want some async drilldowns, then see [demo here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to import drilldown js and also your json sample data is incorrect.

1. all the drilldown series data whose id and main data's id should should match.a
2. also drilldown series data should be together as like here ride data should have to give as *data*.

   ```
               var brandsData = [],
                       drilldownSeries = [];


               brandsData = [{
                       name: "Drive",
                       y: 1,
                       color: "#1068C7",
                       drilldown: "drive"
                   }, {
                       name: "Ride",
                       y: 2,
                       color: "#11A852",
                       drilldown: "ride"
                   }, {
                       name: "Swim",
                       y: 1,
                       color: "#23ED1C",
                       drilldown: "swim"
                   }];
               drilldownSeries = [
                   {
                       "name": "dfdf",
                       "data": [
                           ["Tiger Team", 10]
                       ],
                       id: "swim"
                   }, {
                       "data": [
                           ["Tiger Team", 10]
                       ],
                       id: "drive"
                   }, {
                       "data": [
                           ["Spider Team", 3],
                           ["Bird Team", 1]
                       ],
                       id: "ride"
                   }];
               // Create the chart
               $('#container').highcharts({
                   chart: {
                       type: 'pie'
                   },
                   series: [{
                           name: "Team",
                           colorByPoint: true,
                           data: brandsData
                       }],
                   drilldown: {
                       series: drilldownSeries
                   }
               });
   ```

[pie chart drilldown fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jevddL4/20/)

Comment: @kenyana if u still face problem then let me know.